Workaround for BOOT ERROR on PopOS caused by CPU pipe A FIFO underrun?
After starting laptop and logging in to, I get error:

i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR CPU pipe A FIFO underrun

If I do Ctrl+Alt+F2 then log in, there'll be an "array-index-out-of-bounds" error,
followed by "Failed to mount GNOME Display Manager"
and then computer gets stuck on "Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen".
I'm not able to type any commands to attempt some of the solutions I've found on other posts. And I've tried booting with old kernel but same errors occur.
TLDR: My dad died a month ago, my mom backed up hundreds of family videos of my dad on her laptop and now we can't get it to boot. I know basically nothing about Linux, Ubuntu, PopOS etc and any help fixing boot issue would absolutely mean the world to us.

Dell Latitude 5490 running Pop!_OS 22.04, Virtualbox version 7.0.10

Pictures I took of the errors.

Welcome to AskUbuntu, and I’m sorry for your loss. Pop!OS is not supported here, but you may find a solution involving i915.modeset=0 in your Grub configuration.

One non-destructive and simple solution:

Create an Ubuntu LiveUSB on a USB stick.

Windows instructions - MacOS instructions


Boot the stick (NOT the hard drive)

Select the "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Do NOT install anything!


Use the File Manager to access the data on the hard drive.

Migrate that data onto some other media or online storage account that you can access more conveniently.


